# Write decimal/hex to a file, and not String

Tags: java, string, decimal, hex

If I have a file, and I want to literally write '42' to it (the value, not the string), which for example is 2a in hex, how do I do it? I want to be able to use something like outfile.write(42) or outfile.write(2a) and not write the string to the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For writing binary data you'll want to use a [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html) (such as a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)).

If you find that your data is written as strings, then you're probably using a [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html) (such as a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html) or a [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) wrapped around a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)). Everything named "`*Writer`" or "`*Reader`" deals exclusively with text/`String`s. You'll want to avoid those if you want to write binary data.

If you want to write different data types (and not just plain `byte`s), then you'll want to look into the [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

Comment: Ah! Just late by a second. Good one! :)

Comment: just as an interesting aside: have a look at the java.util.zip.* classes that provide on-the-fly compression. You can pass them to the DataOutputStream constructor and save quite a lot of disk IO

Answer (score 2):

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    String text = "42";
    byte value = Byte.parseByte(text);
    os.write(value);
    os.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29

Comment: There's no need to use DataOutputStream here.

Comment: Could you explain me why? Anyway, I just said that he could use it.:)

Comment: If you want to write bytes, then any OutputStream is ok. Only if you want to write ints/longs/floats/doubles/... directly, then you can use a DataOutputStream to do the conversion to bytes for you.

Comment: I took the liberty of updating the link to point to a current version of the docs. There are too many links to ancient documentation out there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you *just* want to write bytes, the following will suffice:

```
import java.io.*;
...
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("MyFile");
try {
    // Write one byte ...
    out.write((byte) 42);
    // Write multiple bytes ...
    byte[] bytes = ...
    int nosWritten = out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Exception handling is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Actually if you want to write the whole array then "out.write(bytes)" will be ok, you don't need to use the 3-arguments version.

Comment: @Joachim: I know.  It is an example.